# Boto3: How to force route_propagation only after private gateway is attached?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

Is there any wait event for `attach_vpn_gateway()`, like `vpc.wait_until_available()` or something simiar? I'm using this:

```
ec2_clnt.enable_vgw_route_propagation(
    GatewayId=vpg_id,
    RouteTableId=rtl_id
)
```

to do the route propagation after creating the route_table, virtual_private_gateway but it cannot do that as 'attaching' taking time. Is there any AWS/Boto way t make that happen?

-S

Comment: Maybe [EC2.Waiter.CustomerGatewayAvailable](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.CustomerGatewayAvailable)?

Comment: `CustomerGateway` is different than `Virtual Private Gateway`. I have a fixed CG, used by all other VPN connections and I don't think CustomerGateway has anything to do with this issue. Am I wrong?